# how to send SMS to a mobile phone using software program (like yahoo messenger)?

Tags: c++, qt, sms

I am trying to write a small program using Qt to send SMS messages to a mobile phone. Something like what Yahoo Messenger provides. You can send SMS messages to mobile phones if mobile service provider is supported. I would like to know what happens behind the scenes after you click "Send". Especially how does the message you send gets transfered from the server at yahoo to mobile service provider's network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo would've purchased access to (or run their own) SMS gateway. The exact method of transferring the message from Yahoo->Gateway would depend on the gateway's API. Could be XML, could be a proprietary binary format, could be a simple HTTP POST, etc... The SMS gateway would take care of the details of getting the message into the back-end cellular data network and on to the recipient's provider's system.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Can you give some more details or pointers on what you mean by saying "The SMS gateway would take care of the details of getting the message into the back-end cellular data network". This handing over to the back-end cellular data network cannot happen without having an arrangement with the mobile service providers. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yeah. The SMS gateway people will have paid for access to the cell provider's network, and most likely have paid for access to multiple networks. And by network I mean the back-end data networks that the cell data goes over, not the over-the-air part between the phone/tower.

Comment: SUch SMS gateways are known as SMSC's. Every telecom operator runs one. It's unlikely that Yahoo runs one, because that would require Yahoo to register as a telco. The SMSC connects to the telco's internal SS7 network, which in turn will be connected to the SS7 networks of other telco's.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to buy credit with a company like SMS Global ( http://www.smsglobal.com/global/en/ ).  I don't work for them, but I have used them in the past.  You do a simple web request (with your account number), destination phone number and the message.  It deducts credits each time you send an SMS.  Obviously, you write it in to your business plan to cover the costs of this :)

They also offer services whereby you can receive SMS messages to your own web service.

Obviously, there are many other SMS gateways, but if you look at the site and the API you should have a general idea of how it works.